# Golang Reader interface implementation when you already have slice of bytes buffer

Tags: go, io

I am trying to implement a Read and Write method for a program that uploads file []byte to the cloud and downloads file []byte from the cloud.

So far my read method is stuck in an endless read loop reading only same 32KiB.

I am using my opened file to as input to satisfy `io.Copy`.

I am sure my implementation is messy somehow

```
func (s S3File) Read(buffer []byte) (int, error){
if s.mode != "rb"{
    fmt.Println("Wrong mode used")
}
buf, err := s.DownBufferInfo(s.path)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("Error from getting buffer for reader. at `rb` ")
}
allbytes := buf.Bytes()  //BYTES READ FROM A FILE IN THE CLOUD
fmt.Printf("len of bytes from reader --%v", len(allbytes))
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//result := copy(buffer, allbytes)
//n := append(buffer, allbytes...)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
fileBytes := bytes.NewBuffer(allbytes)
result, err := fileBytes.Read(buffer)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(allbytes)
//result, err := fileBytes.Read(buffer)
fmt.Printf("len of bytes read to buffer --%v", result)
fmt.Printf("Total buffer len after read --%v", len(buffer))

return result, err
```

}

EDIT: I was able to get it to work and the answer should follow below.

Comment: So we have no way of knowing what the rest of your program does, but it looks like you're probably downloading a file and only reading the first 32K over and over. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you already have the bytes from the file buffered, why do you need a Read method?

Comment: At some point to create Zip Archives, i need to use io.Copy. This method takes Reader and Writer. Zip.NewWriter takes a Writer . It would be nice if everything played well with the way Golang does things. Anyway, i am close to getting it to work.

Comment: If you need an `io.Reader` from a `[]byte`, that's what `bytes.Reader` is for, and if you need to get a `[]byte` via an `io.Writer`, you use a `bytes.Buffer`. The file must be coming from an `io.Reader` at some point, so you could probably just use that directly. What you have here is just adding more and more layers, getting you further from what should be a simple solution.

Comment: @JimB, please show me your implementation of this in code. If you are right about what you say, then one of my commented methods up there should work directly. That being said, i was able to get it working correctly. It turns out it is not that straight forward to satisfy the reader interface. I will post my answer shortly. I also do not understand the negative points when no one is showing me code.

Answer (score 0):

While my main motivation was to able to use `io.Copy` in my code conveniently, i realized later it was unnecessary with my current Reader which still worked regardless.

Function `func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)` takes source Reader and destination Writer.

My generic reader already provided me with a slice of `[]byte`. All i needed was a Writer to take in those bytes.

Conveniently enough, `dst Writer` implements Writer interface as follows:

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

}

All i did was just do:

```
dst.Write(my_slice_byte)
```

Alternatively i re-wrote my Read implementation but it was unnecessary.